# new File path in java without new object instance

Tags: java, file, path

Is it possible to change the filepath of the File class in java without creating a new instance?

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")); <br>
System.out.println(file.getPath());
```

returns `C:\Users\username` 
now I want to go to the parent directory. I thought I could use something like this

```
file.setPath(file.getParent());
```

but I have to use

```
file = new File(file.getParent());
```

any other way I can achieve the same? Or maybe I could create multiple instances, store them in an array and work with two objects (directories) at the same time?

Comment: Why do you care about whether you create a new instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> Instances of the File class are immutable; that is, once created, the abstract pathname represented by a File object will never change.

So, no, you can't change a File instance. If you want a different value, you have to instantiate a new File.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you missed [`File.getParentFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29):

```
file = file.getParentFile();
```

Comment: That still returns a new instance, though.

Comment: @yshavit: "*Instances of the `File` class are **immutable***" - it's not possible to do this without creating new `File` instance.

Comment: Yes, I know -- and I just posted an answer quoting that exact same bit (before I saw your comment, I swear!). But the OP's question was whether it's possible to mutate a `File`, not just how to get its parent.